# How to read radio_button value on rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to read the selected value of radiobuttons on my Form.Now null value saved in my DB.
Here is my radio buttons:

```
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'der' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel %>
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'die' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel %>
        <%= w.label :Artikel ,'das' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel %>
```

and this is my Controlle:

```
def create
    @word=Word.create(params[:word])
    if @word.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thank you for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give each of your `radio_button` items a second parameter with the value to use:

```
<%= w.radio_button :Artikel, "der" %>
<%= w.radio_button :Artikel, "die" %>
<%= w.radio_button :Artikel, "das" %>
```

Then, `params[:word][:Artikel]` will contain whichever one is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The view should have been

```
<%= w.label :Artikel ,'der' %><%= w.radio_button 'artikel', 'der' %>
<%= w.label :Artikel ,'die' %><%= w.radio_button 'artikel', 'die' %>
<%= w.label :Artikel ,'das' %><%= w.radio_button 'artikel', 'das' %>
```

I assume an attribute called `artikel` exists in the `Word` model.

Comment: Since he's probably using something like `form_for @word do |w|`, you don't need the `'word'` parameters.

Comment: oh yes.. you are right.. i confused it with radio_button_tag. will update the answer